# Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener - react js

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, gesture, touch-event

i'm creating an app with custom drag and drop events i've written alot of code can't share it over here due to unlimited props and other data coming in it . It's a calender with events . the user can drag and drop the events from one date to another and also can drop it on time aswell [Screenshot of calender with draggable event please have a look into it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5c9k.png)

i've uploaded the website with debuggers in all functions ...

**how to generate the problem **

when we drag the events it will work fine .(Open inspect element) now drag the event with touch of screen it will generate the error [Screenshot of error have a look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KS7Vy.png) , [screenshot of error with open dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YB2HV.png)

Please Help i've tried all of the solution found on the internet about this issue but didn't fixed it please don't mention duplicate of this solution i've tried all of them but didn't success

how to open the events on calendar on website [Please have a look in this screen it has the steps of opening the events calendar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xjOHN.png)

For code and debugging please Visit [Link to my website with error](https://afnandemo.surge.sh/)

> i have added a debugger on all functions just for you so you can debug it ... Thanks....

Answer (score 0):

I had to use the  component from react-event-injector https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-event-injector. Also know that touch events use a different API and methods than mouse events, that threw me for a bit. That might be common knowledge though!

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31249239)